# passthru doesn't work in Xampp 1.7.5

Tags: php, background-process

I have installed Xampp 1.7.5 in my linux system (Fedora 10). I have a requirement in which a PHP script has to run in the background.

I am using this passthru:

```
<?php
passthru("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php ".$argv_parameter." >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
?>
```

PHP is not running in background. When I execute it manually, it works fine.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: i always use nohup with my background php tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using with quotes as below:

```
passthru("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php $argv_parameter >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
```

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas - try adding a second parameter to the `passthru` (see [here](http://uk.php.net/passthru)) function, to see what the return value of the command is. Failing that, try the `system` command - that's how I do it in a CLI program I am working on.

Also, ensure that you are not running in safe mode - check the output of phpinfo() in your browser to find out.